# Display total number of items from while loop outside of it php

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, count

I have a PHP while loop and i'm trying to use a counter to display the total number of items (`.question`) that are within it. I'm trying to echo the contents of $child_i outside of the while loop to do this but the code below doesn't work. Whats the best way of achieving this?

**EDIT**
Updated to show full code

```
<?php if( have_rows('faqs') ): ?>
   <ul class="responsive-accordion responsive-accordion-default bm-larger">
      <?php while( have_rows('faqs') ): the_row(); ?>
        <li>
           <div class="responsive-accordion-head"><span class="ico arrow-right"></span><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?> <span class="faq-counter">
           <!-- TRYING TO ECHO $CHILD_I ON THE LINE BELOW BUT NOT WORKING -->
           <?php echo($child_i); ?> Questions</span></div>
           <!-- $CHILD_I IS DEFINED ON THE NEXT LINE -->
           <?php if( have_rows('questions') ): $child_i = 0; ?>
              <!-- THIS ECHO WORKS -->
              <div class="responsive-accordion-panel <?php echo($child_i); ?>">
                <?php while( have_rows('questions') ): the_row(); ?>
                  <div class="question">
                     <h6><?php the_sub_field('question'); ?></h6>   
                     <p><?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?></p>
                  </div>
                <?php $child_i++; endwhile; ?>
            </div>
           <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('questions') ): ?>
           </div>
        </li>   
   <?php endwhile; // while( has_sub_field('to-do_lists') ): ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; // if( get_field('to-do_lists') ): ?>
```

Comment: At the first point `$child_i` isn't defined! You have to print it after the while loop

Comment: Its defined in the sub while loop. Even if it was defined on the parent loop, based on the code above, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @egr103: I'm not seeing what the issue is. Using a loop to count is pretty straightforward. Declare the variable as 0, increment by 1 in each iteration of the loop, then output the variable. Where are you actually outputting the value?

Comment: Don't enclose $child_i in brackets - from the docs `echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Code now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$questions = get_field('questions'); $size=count($questions); echo $size;
```

Comment: <?php echo($child_i); ?> instead of  <?php $questions = get_field('questions'); $size=sizeof($questions); echo $size; ?>

Comment: I guess you meant the other way around. Either way it doesn't work :(

Comment: @egr103 Try same code but just change `$size=sizeof($questions); ` to `$size = count($questions)` .. Let me know the output.

Comment: Bingo. Although I had to change get_field to get_sub_field as well.